# Creating a "snake" counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm just trying to get the logic straight and using Python to help me do it.  Ultimately, I need to solve this problem using ImageJ macro language.

I have no idea if I'm using the right term, but I'd like to create a "snake" counter.

```
x = 1
number = 12
maxVal = 3
minVal = 1

for i in xrange(number):
    %do something
    x = incrementSnakeCounter(x, maxVal, minVal)
    print("i = ", i)
    print("x = ", x)
```

The "snake" part is making the counter go up only to the `maxVal`, repeating that number on the next iteration, counting down to the `minVal`, repeating that value on the next iteration, and repeating the process.

For instance, in the above

I'd like the following to happen :

```
i = 0
x = 1

i = 1
x = 2

i = 2
x = 3

i = 3
x = 3

i = 4
x = 2

i = 5
x = 1

i = 6
x = 1

i = 7
x = 2

i = 8
x = 3

i = 9
x = 3

i = 10
x = 2

i = 11
x = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a silly mathematical solution:

```
def snake(low, high, x):
    k = (high-low+1)
    return k - int(abs(x % (2*k) + low - k - 0.5))

[snake.snake(1,3,x) for x in range(8)]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Great solution!  This works perfectly in my application.  Just needed to replace `int` with `floor` since `int` isn't available in ImageJ macro language.

Answer (score 5):

You will find some useful utils in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import chain, cycle

def snake(lower, upper):
    return cycle(chain(range(lower, upper+1), range(upper, lower-1, -1)))

> s = snake(1,3)

> [next(s) for _ in range(10)]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: This is a good solution.  Unfortunately, I need to implement it in ImageJ macro language.  I should have made it clear that python was for illustration only.

Comment: This isn't going to work if your min or max values ever change.

Comment: @agf1997 imagej-macro has its own tag on stackoverflow. So sorry for that. I guess the logic itself should not be be too difficult to pin down in any language or pseudo-code.

Comment: @GlenPierce It was never mentioned in the question that they ever were to change.

Comment: @schwobaseggl  Yes I know there's an imageJ-macro tag.  Just trying to get the logic straight.

Comment: @agf1997 dawg's answer has a modulo-based approach that should translate well to most languages.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Agree ... before I posted I'd been playing with modulo but couldn't quite get it to work.  I'll play with his solution.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Add a conditional to determine if x should be increasing or decreasing at any given point within the loop.

```
x = 1
number = 12
maxVal = 3
minVal = 1

for i in xrange(number):
    %do something
    if(xIsIncreasing)
        x = incrementSnakeCounter(x, maxVal, minVal)
    else
        x = decrementSnakeCounter(x, maxVal, minVal)
    print("i = ", i)
    print("x = ", x)
```

Then inside your incrementSnakeCounter() change the value of xIsIncreasing to false when x == maxVal and inside your decrementSnakeCounter() to true when x == minVal (you'll have to do some work to make sure that you're staying at the same value twice in a row, I don't have time right now to solve that part for you).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a little custom generator.

The key is to create a list of the pattern you want to repeat `[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]` and then index that with the modulo of the length to get the repeating behavior:

```
def snake(x, max_v=3, min_v=1):
    cnt=0
    sn=list(range(min_v, max_v+1,1))+list(range(max_v, min_v-1,-1))
    while cnt<x:
        yield cnt, sn[cnt%len(sn)]
        cnt+=1
```

Then:

```
for i,x in snake(12):
    print("i=",i)
    print("x=",x)   
    print()
```

Prints:

```
i= 0
x= 1

i= 1
x= 2

i= 2
x= 3

i= 3
x= 3

i= 4
x= 2

i= 5
x= 1

i= 6
x= 1

i= 7
x= 2

i= 8
x= 3

i= 9
x= 3

i= 10
x= 2

i= 11
x= 1
```